# React native: How to combine external and inline styles?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is a part of a _renderRow-function. I have some basic styles for a button, and also a style that is read from a variable on the row. In this example it's '#f00' but it could be a variable, like thisColor. How can I combine an external style with an inline style?

Something like this, but this doesn't work:

```
<TouchableHighlight style={[styles.button]{ backgroundColor: '#f00'}}
```

Or do I have to nest it with a container inside the TouchableHightlight and put the inline style on that element instead?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Your brackets are wrong. If you intend to continue to use the array syntax,  Use this instead:

```
<TouchableHighlight style={[styles.button,{ backgroundColor: '#f00'}]}
```

Comment: A benefit of this is you could combine multiple external styles.

Comment: This answer worked both in iOS as well in Web using Expo.

Answer (score 24):

Can use the spread syntax:

```
<TouchableHighlight style={{ ...styles.button, backgroundColor: '#f00'}}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice alternative. I haven't seen the spread syntax in the docs for styles that much, so I'll go for accepting the other answer, but both work great!

Comment: But that answer doesn't look correct, IMO, did you test it?  It is passing an array of style objects, rather than a single, combined style object.

Comment: @Niclas if `styles.button` is a valid rect styles object, the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Actually the other one with the array works, also with multiple styles.xxx and the spread one doesn't. Apparently I didn't try it correctly. When I try `<Text style={{ ...styles.centered, styles.textDay, backgroundColor: '#f0f'}}>` I get **Unexpected token**, and `<Text style={{ ...styles.centered, backgroundColor: '#f0f'}}>` gives **In this environment the sources for assign MUST be an object.** Very weird, I'm using React 15.2.1 and React Native 0.29.0.

Comment: Same error -  **In this environment the sources for assign MUST be an object.**; the spread syntax looks nice, but the array one is the one that works.

Comment: this is a reply to very old comments, but the reason the two above errors occurred, is because you need to add the spread operator "..." to each style when spreading multiple styles.. .like this: {{ ...styles.centered, ...styles.textDay, backgroundColor: '#f0f"}}  - note that in the comment above that the "..." is missing from styles.textDay  (hope this little reply clears things up for peeps in >=2019)

Comment: Works on iOS, but does not work in Web browser using Expo.

Comment: Similar to @Jacobdo, this works on Android but was the source of a bug for me in the Web version of Expo. Technically, the question was about React Native and not Expo, though.

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct answer, tested in React Native 0.44.2:

```
<TouchableHighlight style={{...styles.button, ...{backgroundColor: '#f00'}}}>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping the OP out, can you please add some more explanation / official documentation which may help others who see your answer understand the "why" behind it?

Comment: I tested myself doing some tests with previous comments, and I got it working ;) Official documentation it´s not ok...

Answer (score 0):

Some components might accept callback as style, so for those cases this code should work:

```
import React, { type ComponentProps } from 'react'
import { Pressable, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

const baseButtonStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  base: {
    // your styles here...
  },
})


export const Button = ({
  children,
  style,
  ...rest
}: { children: React.ReactNode } & ComponentProps<typeof Pressable>) => {
  return (
    <Pressable
      style={
        typeof style === 'function' ? (state) => [baseButtonStyles.base, style(state)] : [baseButtonStyles.base, style]
      }
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </Pressable>
  )
}
```