# React Native - Inline Style and Properties doesn't working on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, styles

I'm doing a multiplatform app in react-native, but some layout properties are working in Android but not in IOS. After some search in our code, we figure out that the inline properties are the thing giving us throuble, like in that code:

```
 <Button
    style={principal_style.botoes}
    backgroundColor='#e3e3e3'
    onPress={() => this.logaUser() }>
    <Text style={principal_style.btntxtstylewhite}>{this.state.txtEntrar}</Text>
 </Button>
```

The backgroundColor propertie is completely ignored, and that problem repeats in every CSS propertie used that way, width, height, everhthing. Even if I put the properties inside the Style prop, it doesn't do anything, like in that code:

```
 <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', }}>
      <Text style={{color:'#ffffff', fontSize:12, textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 20,}}>V - 0.02</Text>
 </View>
```

Now, about the external Stylesheet, they work perfectly, like the first code fragment, it has a style prop called principal_style.botoes, here is the code:

```
 botoes: {
    flex: 2,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    height:70,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginLeft: 40,
    marginRight: 40,
    borderRadius: 20,
    marginBottom: 20
 },
```

I don't know what else to do, maybe some react command, anything to work with, the inline style should work in IOS, right?

Please, give me some light about that.

**EDIT 1**

I could solve the first problem with that

```
 <TouchableHighlight style={[styles.button,{ backgroundColor: '#f00'}]}
```

**CREDITS:** [Answer from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40117858/3714926)

**EDIT 2 - SOLUTION**

I managed to solve the problems, turns out that the whole thing was caused by I mistake, the flex propertie was wrong, i had mixed it with other ways of height, and that made the whole text disappear, now everything is work perfectly, the advice that I can give to anyone ho gets that kind of problem is that everything works if you do the right way.

proper way to overwrite a external style to work in both platforms

```
<TouchableHighlight style={[styles.button,{ backgroundColor: '#f00'}]}
```

I forgot to mention that I was using the **NATIVE-BASE button**

Comment: react-native button works differently on Android and IOS, check color property https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html#color

Comment: `botoes: {   flex: 2,}` The max is 1

Comment: Thank you, guys, that help to find the way, I will explain what I was doing wrong.