# React Native Array Notation with Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have an object that I am trying to pass a style to. With regular JS I can pass

```
<ObjectName       
  containerStyle={[
    {marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 30},
    {borderBottomWidth: 3},
     keyboardOpen ? null : {marginHorizontal: 30},
  ]} />
```

However when I try to do the same thing in Typescript I get the error that the given objects have no properties in common with FlexStyle, Object is delcared as follows

```
export const ObjectName = (props: {containerStyle?: FlexStyle}) => {...}
```

How would I combine those styles with array notation in TS, or if I can't what would be the best method to use?

Comment: Not knowing what your FlexStyle type/interface entails, maybe you need ```props: {containerStyle?: FlexStyle[]}``` if you are trying to pass an array?

Comment: FlexStyle is direct from React-native
`import { FlexStyle } from 'react-native';`

Also, its not an array, its Array notation. Just one of many SO questions about the JS side of array notations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117640/react-native-how-to-combine-external-and-inline-styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular `style` prop combines multiple objects into one if you pass an array. I believe you can emulate this behaviour with a code similar to the below example:

```
const ObjectName = (props: {containerStyle?: FlexStyle | Array<FlexStyle> }) => {
    let containerStyle;
    if(Array.isArray(props.containerStyle)) {
        containerStyle = Object.assign({}, ...props.containerStyle) as FlexStyle 
    }
    else {
    containerStyle = props.containerStyle
    }
    return <View style={containerStyle}/>
}
```

Not sure if the is the absolutely necessary condition for you, but if you want to be able to pass either a style object or an array of objects, Typescript should be able to digest it.