# React Native: Is there any way to make inline styles having a state to turn out external styles?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I combine an external style with an inline style which has a state? I just want to place all styles into the style module.

```
<View
  style={[
    styles.buttonAcceptDinamic,
    {
      backgroundColor: !this.state.micState ? null : 'rgba(255,255,255,.4)',
    },
  ]}>
  <Icon
    name={this.state.micState ? 'mic-off' : 'mic'}
    color="white"
    size={30}
  />
</View>;
```

([React native: How to combine external and inline styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117640/react-native-how-to-combine-external-and-inline-styles)) This solution has an inline style having no state.

Edited: Code works properly. I just wanted to get rid of inline styling having state because VSCode and Error Lens(VSCode Extension) gives me a warning.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly:

```
<View
  style={{
    ...styles.buttonAcceptDinamic,
    backgroundColor: !this.state.micState ? null : 'rgba(255,255,255,.4)',
  }}>
</View>
```

Using the spread operator seems the best way to go.

Comment: Why not? Do you have a reason?

Comment: Ya, the array syntax looks much cleaner and is the recommended way to do it. For reference, check out some open source lib code on github.

Comment: I actually disagree with the "cleaner" part, that's a pretty subjective thing. But I didn't know it was the recommended way to go. Does documentation state that?

Comment: Consider this, you have to combine multiple stylesheets, using array notation it's simply `[styles.style1, styles.style2, styles.style3 ...]`, with spread operator:  
`[{ ...styles.style1, ...styles.style2, ...styles.style3 ... more styles }]`. 

Really comes in handy when using multiple stylesheets. Your statement "best way to go" doesn't really hold well in similar situations

Comment: "Best way to go" may be going too far, but note the "seems" in front of it. I didn't say it was absolutely the best way to go.

And, yeah. You use a few less characters typing it out. If you have to do a lot of external styles the array syntax is nicer.

I still think the syntax with ... looks cleaner with a small number of styles or a decent amount of inline stlyes.

Answer (score 0):

An example using hooks but achieves the same thing, you had an issue with your syntax:

```
 <Text style={[styles.paragraph, isValid ? {'color': 'red'} : "" ]}>
```

Expo: https://snack.expo.io/rLwktDEHM

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {

  const [isValid, setValid] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={[styles.paragraph, isValid ? {'color': 'red'} : "" ]}>
        Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable url.
      </Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setValid(v => !v)}>
          <Text>
            Change State
          </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Card>
        <AssetExample />
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```